# Function for ploting a matrix in ipython using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I have created a matrix:

```
s1=np.random.randn(1000,1000)
v1=la.eigvals(s1)
matrix1=np.matrix(v1)
```

I want to plot the matrix in `ipython`.

What appropriate `matplotlib` function should I use?

Comment: Is better when you put multiline code in a block, it improves readability and the chances of a good answer. Your title also should go straight at what you need, adjectives sometimes are not needed.
Always put the tag of the language you are using, that will attract the attention of more users as the languages tags are more populated.

Comment: It will be very helpful if you specify how the visualization should be (what kind of plot do you need) and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple example to "plot" a matrix:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

S  = np.random.randn(100,100)

# Make symmetric so everything is real
S += S.T
W,V = np.linalg.eigh(S)

import pylab as plt
plt.imshow(V,interpolation="none")
plt.show()
```

[image]